# Is it possible to make PayPal payment without redirecting to PayPal website using WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment

I want to make payment through `PaypPal` without redirecting to `PayPal` website.

I am using `plugin PayPal` for `Woo Commerce` and method direct (as I understand it's only way to make out without redirect)

But seems to me it works only for USA but my recipient is in Germany.

So is it possible to make such kind of payment to Germany? And if yes so how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Cool ,but how? in the list there only USA and CA?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Payments Pro, which is what allows you to accept credit cards directly on your site without any redirect at all, is only available in the US, UK, and Canada, so the PayPal seller account would have to be based in one of those countries in order to get approved for Pro.

If you can't get approved for Pro then your only option is to use Express Checkout, but you can configure it to allow "guest checkout" so that users don't have to create an account to pay.

Comment: So as I understand right its no posibility to make payments without redirecting if seller is German correct?
And also can you tell me where is  exactly "guest checkout" option should be set

Comment: For guest checkout you need to make sure the PayPal Account Optional setting is enabled in both the plugin and in your PayPal account profile.  You also need to make sure guest checkout is enabled in the general WooCommerce checkout settings, and you may also need to disable the option in the Express Checkout settings to "Use WordPress Locale Code".  One more thing is that you need to set the landing page option in the EC settings to Billing.

Comment: So yes it used to  work. But when I tested it few time it just stop working, and thats all.
I tried to clean cache and cookie, nothing happend, what the problem can be?